# dealloc in NSOperation

Tags: iphone, ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, dealloc

i have a NSOperationQueue with NSOperation, in my NSOperation .h i have this property:

```
@interface MyOperationClass : NSOperation 
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObject *myObject;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myArray;

@end
```

and this in the dealloc of the NSOperation in the .m file:

```
- (void)dealloc {
[__fetchedResultsController release];
[__managedObjectContext release];
[myObject release];
[myArray release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

in another class i add the operation in the queue in this way:

```
MyOperationClass *myOperation = [[MyOperationClass alloc] init];
[myOperationQueue addOperation:myOperation];
[myOperation release];
```

but give me a bad_exc_access on the line of [myArray release]; what i wrong?

EDIT: i notice that in the code i do this:

wikiEpisodeArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:otherArray];

maybe is this? i don't have initialized it with [NSMutableArray alloc] ?

**EDIT 2:**
i have another similar problem, i have also this variable:

```
@property (nonatimc, retain) NSString *previousTime;
```

and i initialized it in this way:

```
previousTime = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

and in the code i never release it, only in the dealloc, and now i receive a bad exc access on this line:

```
[previousTime release];
```

in the dealloc...
why?

Comment: Sounds to me like something *else* released your "`MyOperationClass`" `myArray` object.  If it were my code, I'd run Xcode's Instruments and use the ObjectAlloc template to see who is retaining and releasing the elements of your object.

Comment: oh... heh.  I also see the ARC keywords "`strong`" in your interface declaration. I don't have a lot of experience with ARC yet, personally, but I thought the big "win" of ARC was that you didn't have to mess with managing dealloc or releases.

Comment: i don't have ARC in my project, so i have to change it in nonatomic retain?...in fact i want do another question on stack overflow about this...

Comment: if you are using ARC, you don't have to release your member variables. Are you using ARC? Also, try turning on zombies and see if that points out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have arc, then you have to use (nonatomic, retain) (or assign if not retaining it).

Also, any object that you don't explicitly alloc, should be returned autoreleased. so don't release them.

If you want to create a mutable array that you own with another one you should do

```
[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:aArray];
```

for the NSString, use (nonatomic, copy), also, again, when you assign a nsstring with @"something" you are assigning an autoreleased one overriding the previous [NSString alloc] init].

So, if you want to own the string you should do:

```
[NSString alloc] initWithString:aString];
```

Comment: thank you very much diego, you are very helpful, so i change the nonatomic, copy and i not change the [previousTime release] right?

Answer (score 1):

you might not have allocated memory to object that you are releasing

Comment: yes, Piero's line "`[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:otherArray];`" implies that his "`myArray`" object is autoreleased... so that's why he is seeing the `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` crash

Comment: ok thanks, and instead the strong nonatomic? i can use it? or it's better nonatomic retain? i don't have ARC...

Comment: strong and retain are same as they both create strong references to the variable

Comment: where did you initialize your string ...which method?